# Implementation of two listviews in one frame

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i'm working on two listviews in a same activity in which there are 3 strings in 1st one and the 2nd listview is blank . i want to trasfer the values of first list into second list, whenever any value is pressed.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = (String) listView1
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);


            secoundList.add(itemValue);
            firstList.remove(position);


            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                            + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    });
```

But everytime i get error in logcat that "the content of adapter has changed but listview didnot recieve any notification " The error of the log cat that "make sure the content of adapter is not modified from a background thread"

Comment: if you want to modify any list view, you have to set adapter for the list view. read this tutorial it will helps you  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call this method after modifying the list.

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, then you r trying to selected listitem from one list you want to show that selected list item in second list view.?

I will give You question according to what i understand.

so first of all you need to initilize the first list with item.

```
ListView listview1 = findViewBId(---------);
ListView listview2 = findViewBId(---------);

ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("abc");
list1.add("pqr");
list1.add("pqr");
--------------------

ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list1 );
 listView1.setAdapter(adapter1 );

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list2 );
 listView1.setAdapter(adapter2 );
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);


onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

list2.add(list1.get(position));
adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: inline 'MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }'   I used this method right below when adapter is updated but now the issue is the values are not coming in listview 2 .

Comment: I think you doesn't need to call the runOnUIthread(). because u r already working on ui thread. so you doesn't need it. runOnUIthread() is used when u r doing so work in backgroung in asyn task and work on other thread and you want to immediately show values in ui thread. plz try the above approach it will work.